# Jquery Hover Opacity, what am I missing here?

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity

I'm a little (more like a very) rusty on my jquery knowledge.  for some reason I can't figure out what I am missing here to make the blue box fade when the green box is being hovered over.

the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover-text").hover({
    $(".hover-hide").animate({
        opacity: 0.4,
    }, 500);
    });​
```

the html:

```
 <div class="hover-hide">
    <div class="hover-text">
        BLAH
    </div>
    </div>
```

the css:

```
 .hover-hide{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:30px;
    }
    .hover-text{
    color:white;
    background-color:green;
    padding:10px;
    width:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    }​​
```

Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of `.hover` is a callback function, it should be `$('.hover-text').hover(function(){`.
Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TsW6n/).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `function` after the `.hover` call. Also, you're missing a closing bracket and parenthesis at the end of your `.ready();`

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     

    $(".hover-text").hover( function() {     
        $(".hover-hide").animate({ opacity: 0.4, }, 500);     
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TMZhJ/